# Build number increment not reflected in AssemblyVersion

Tags: c#, build-process, assemblies

I've browsed through some of the discussion on auto-incrementing build numbers, but in the impatience of youth decided to roll my own and re-invent the wheel.  I know there are probably better ways to go about this (which I'm definitely going to investigate), but my question centers more around the Assembly and/or Version classes.

My approach was to write a separate exe (BuildIncrementer) that takes a command line parameter for file name, does a regex match on the contents to grab the `[assembly: AssemblyVersion...]` string, do the modifications that I want (increment the build number, etc.), then write the contents back to the file.  This approach works as-is.

The next thing I did was in the project that I wanted to use this on, I set up a pre-build command line that is simply the command to execute that BuildIncrementer.exe on this project's AssemblyInfo.cs file.  This too works, updating the assembly info as desired.

The problem comes when I run the project, it sends an email containing the current version, obtained with `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()`.  BUT, the version showing up is the *previous* version.  When my AssemblyInfo.cs says `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.2.49667")]`, I get sent 1.0.1.45660, which was the previous build.

Anyone have any ideas why that might be?

Comment: If you know that there is a better way to do it, unless this is an academic exercise, why don't you abandon your BuildIncrementer and use the built-in facilities of Visual Studio?

Otherwise, your process sounds like it should work. I'm assuming that the version # that is reported by the Assembly code is always the previous version compared to the AssemblyInfo.cs file and it isn't just a version number that is frozen in time.

Comment: Yep, it's an academic exercise. Just playing around with a DIY solution.

Yes, the version # reported is always the previous, not a frozen number.

I'm wondering if maybe it has to do with the order that projects get built?  For instance, could the assembly info be put into the exe even before the pre-build command runs?

Answer (score 0):

I think your exe runs before your entire build process gets completed(or gets started) hence reflecting an old vesion...maybe

Comment: This happens even if I build the project, double-check the AssemblyInfo file (and see the updated version), and then start the exe.  Are you saying that maybe the exe is getting built before the pre-build is complete?  Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of a pre-build command?